# Object 'cannot be cast' using Hibernate in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm running Hibernate 5.x in Play for Scala 2.5. Hibernate accesses SAP Hana database.

Problem happens when I touch the code and Play compiles automatically. Right after the code compiles, when I run the application, if the code invokes a Hibernate function I get the exception below `admin.dates.DateHib cannot be cast to admin.dates.DateHib` where `DateHib` is an Hibernate annotated class. Note that I don't change neither Hibernate objects nor functions that use Hibernate objects. Still, when I run the code after editing it I get the `cannot be cast` error.

The workaround is to restart Play, but I cannot restart Play everytime I touch the code.

I'm not sure that it has to do anything with this problem, but I'm running in the same application Slick 3.1 accessing MySql.

Any ideas?

This is the code that fails:

```
 def findLastDayHoliday (month: Int, year: Int) = {
     val session = HibernateUtil.sessionFactoryBank.openSession
     try {
         val query = session.createQuery("from DateHib where month=:month and year=:year")
         query.setMaxResults(1)
         query.setParameter("year", year)
         query.setParameter("month", month)
         val list = query.list.asScala.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[DateHib])
         if (list.length>0)
             Some(list(0))
         else
              None
      }
      catch {
        case e:Exception => throw new Exception ("Failure: " + e.getMessage)
      }
      finally session.close
   }
```

And this is the exception:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[Exception: Failure in findLastDayHoliday: admin.dates.DateHib cannot be cast to admin.dates.DateHib]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failure in findLastDayHoliday: admin.dates.DateHib cannot be cast to admin.dates.DateHib
        at admin.dates.DateObjDAO.findLastDayHoliday(DateObjDAO.scala:126)
        at ds.formula.process.RunFormula.getLastDayHoliday(RunFormula.scala:665)
        at ds.formula.process.RunFormula.getFromToDates(RunFormula.scala:610)
        at ds.formula.process.RunFormula.run(RunFormula.scala:145)
        at ds.formula.process.RunFormula.doTest(RunFormula.scala:69)
        at ds.formula.process.RunFormula$$anonfun$test$1.apply(RunFormula.scala:61)
        at ds.formula.process.RunFormula$$anonfun$test$1.apply(RunFormula.scala:59)
        at login.Authentication$LoggedAction$$anonfun$invokeBlock$1.apply(LoggedAction.scala:39)
        at login.Authentication$LoggedAction$$anonfun$invokeBlock$1.apply(LoggedAction.scala:34)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
```

Comment: Guess a classloader issue resulting in refs using different versions of the same class (and so different `Class` instances for same class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that cchantep is right. Every time play reloads your application it uses a different classloader.

I see two things that might be happening:

1. You are using a few singletons that are loaded using the classloader initially create by play, and when play reloads those singletons are not being destroyed, leading the kind of problem you see.
2. You use a few services that you should shutdown and restart when play reloads, but you don't, which leads to the same problem as point 1 above.

But first, let's make sure this is the above is correct, see how you can diagnose that more precisely: I would add log entries in the failing code to print the classloader used in your different objects.

```
     val list = query.list.asScala.toList.map { e => 
       log.debug("Class loaded with: " + e.getClass.getClassLoader)
       log.debug("Current class loader: " + classOf[DateHib].getClassLoader)
       e.asInstanceOf[DateHib]
     }
```

My guess is that the classloader printed would be the same when you first start your application, but that after play reloads, that the first classloader printed doesn't change, but the second one is a new instance... give it a try.

As for fixing those issues, you should look into play's lifecycle hooks: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up

Comment: This is what I get when I print the log, apparently versions are different?`Class loaded with: ReloadableClassLoader(v1){file:/C:/visual/apps/target/scala-2.11/classes/}
Current class loader: ReloadableClassLoader(v2){file:/C:/visual/apps/target/scala-2.11/classes/}`

Comment: You are correct, I'm loading on startup a Play class that implements Quartz `akka-quartz-scheduler`, when Play starts the scheduler is triggered and runs in background to initiate any process when needed. Apparently I need to unload the scheduler when Play is reloaded?

Comment: Yes, you end up using 2 different class loaders. Yes, you need to unload that scheduler. However, as playframework shuts down its own actor system, I'm not sure what is happening to your scheduler. Are you using play's actor system? is you `findLastDayHoliday` function called through the scheduler?

Comment: I'm using play's actor system. the scheduler calls `findLastDayHoliday` and so does the function that throws the error.